# Buying a parked domain if the contact email bounces

Tags: domains, email, purchase

I'm trying to buy a domain which is parked, but the contact email address listed on the page itself bounces. I looked up the WHOIS data and there are no email addresses or phone numbers listed. There are  way too many hits on facebook / linkedin to try just searching for the name.

What recourses do I have to try to get into contact with the owner?

**UPDATE:**
Hosted on the same IP are 206 identical "parked" pages, whose sole difference is the domain and the email address (always "info@[domain].it"): http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3A151.1.48.220
Whois info shows contact information for none (that I sampled) but all with different names o_O

Comment: You could always _not_ buy domains from domain squatters. It's sort of like clicking on spam email links and buying from spam sites. You're just encouraging more spammers.

Comment: *sigh* i know... when I first started looking for it I was rather hoping this was just a domain the owner who had a "main site" was sitting on for now. Blargh but I want the domain >_<

Comment: Be strong! Fight it! Check to see how long those domains have been registered for. It could be that the owner is just letting the domains go after a year if they're not performing or are unable to sell it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to do some detailed research.

1. Google (Bing) for the email address to find other places it's mentioned
2. For each parked domain that mentions the email address, do a WHOIS lookup to see if a phone number or email address is listed.
3. To each distinct physical or postal address you find using WHOIS, send a real physical letter
4. Do additional searches for those addresses - you may find details of the company itself (perhaps a web page)
5. If you find the email address in other places (not parked domains), follow through to see if you can link the address to anything. Some sites have direct-messaging, others provide ways to email users.

Take detailed notes as you go, else you're likely to go around in circles.

Comment: I did an IP search, and it returned pages and pages of identically parked domains, with different names, all with the erroneous email addresses "info@_____.it" :-\ All the domains have different names attached, and none have contact information

Comment: It's all very odd - anyone owning a genuine parked domain should be interested in a sale. Having bogus email addresses and different names gives me a *very* bad vibe.

Comment: yeah it makes no sense to me either... wasn't there some movie where the villain bought up almost all of some resource, and then sold it at a huge profit when people were starving or whatever? Maybe this person thinks he can do that to the .it tld by registering ~200 domains o_O